# search and replace with wild characters as LITERALS

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

i am trying to search for `[Panels] like "*,*"`

within a worksheet and unfortunately instead of retrieving exactly that string it retrieves anything like:

```
[Panels] like "*blah,*"
[Panels] like "*blah,123123*"
```

i need it to be EXACTLY `[Panels] like "*,*"`

and i suppose that perhaps i would to do this in VBA instead of manually? if this is not possible to do manually how would i do a search and replace a different way?

Comment: I don't get it.  How is "*.*" not like "*blah,*" -- did I misread something?  Are you looking for the asterisks themselves?  If so, why use like instead of equals?

Comment: MJB i am search for the string "[Panels] like "*,*""

Comment: Then why not say [Panels] = "*,*".  That should not treat the asterisks as wild cards.  If it still does, then I guess you have to escape them -- perhaps something like [Panels] = "\*,\*"

Comment: so that is my question, please let me know what works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tilde (~) escapes *, ?, and ~ in Excel's find and replace.

```
[Panels] like "~*blah,~*"
```